# BeautifulSoup module error (html parser) while using Seaborn

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, seaborn

I am using seaborn to draw a graph.

First I wanted to get the names of the sample dataset.

`sns.get_dataset_names()`

but this returned an error :

```
The code that caused this warning is on line 384 of the file C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\envs\seaborn\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor
```

How can I fix this problem? I know I can just ignore this error but I want to get rid of it so that it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, this is not an error. It is simply a warning.
You would have to step into that seaborn function in `utils.py` to add that in.

```
def get_dataset_names():
    """Report available example datasets, useful for reporting issues."""
    # delayed import to not demand bs4 unless this function is actually used
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    http = urlopen('https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/')
    gh_list = BeautifulSoup(http, 'html.parser')  #<-- you'd need to add the parameter here

    return [l.text.replace('.csv', '')
            for l in gh_list.find_all("a", {"class": "js-navigation-open"})
            if l.text.endswith('.csv')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was just an warning but just wanted to get rid of it.

Comment: Ya it is rather annoying.